# How to Upload Sqlite3 DB in AppData When Install Electron.js App

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am doing one simple Project using Electron, React and SQLite Database.
Everything working fine in locally with my readymade database.
After Build it wouldn't works as expected. I need to upload My database to %Appdata% folder.
Please help me to do this.

To Connect DB I use this.

```
const path = require('path');
const dbdatapath=path.join(app.getPath('userData'), "db.sqlite3");
const database = new sqlite3.Database(dbdatapath, (err) => {
    if (err){ console.log('Database opening error: '+ err);}
    else{
        console.error('Database Connected sucess ');
    }
});
```

I have some Predefined Master Data to work this App.

I need to upload Database when Install. Or let us know any other way to achieve this?

Comment: from the code it should be working as expected but can you please provide some more information.

Comment: How did you finally manage this on installation?

Comment: Uploaded Sqlite DB using extraresources(This folder files uploaded in resource path) and using "path.join(process.resourcesPath, "sqlite.db")" we read data.